# Concat, group and sumarize

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concat, group, and summarize some data, and then delete the rows.
I was successful about concat, group, and summarize, but I got lost about how to delete the rest of the sentence in a row, let me share the code:

```
Sub CombineRows()
    
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Dic    As Variant
    Dim arr    As Variant
        On Error Resume Next
                Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
                Set WorkRng = Range("$AE:$AF").Select
                Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                arr = WorkRng.Value
                    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
                        Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
                    Next
                'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            WorkRng.ClearContents
        WorkRng.Range("A2").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
    WorkRng.Range("B2").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.itemS)
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Before I run:

[image]

After I run:

[image]

Basically, how can I delete the rest of the content of the same row after I group and summarize? I want to delete the duplicated content from the data that I concatenated.

I applied the suggested code, but seems like something did not work well, the last number disappeared:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOI6i.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uyfW.png)

Here is the Spreadsheet file:
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LuN6HpNBFH1403m-J31oPu-HVdasCwtZ?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
Sub CombineRows_close_to_original() ' please note that the rows in the selected part of the table are processed independently of the contents of the rows in the rest of the table, which may violate the integrity of the data
    Const AREA = "AE:AF"
    
    Dim WorkRng As Range, arr, Dic As Object, i As Long
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set WorkRng = Intersect(.Range(AREA), .UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)) ' select non-empty area in target columns "AE:AF" without header
        arr = WorkRng
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
        Next

        WorkRng(1).Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
        WorkRng(2).Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
        
        If WorkRng.rows.Count > Dic.Count Then _
            WorkRng(1).Offset(Dic.Count).Resize(WorkRng.rows.Count - Dic.Count).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: result 1]

**Option 2**

```
Sub CombineRows3()
    Const START_CELL = "AE2"
    
    Dim rows_to_remove As Range, cl As Range, key As String, Dic As Object, i As Long
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set cl = .Range(START_CELL)
        i = 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(cl) 'walk through the cells down from START_CELL to the first empty cell
            key = cl.Value
            If Dic.exists(key) Then ' if the key is already in dic >> the key is duplicated >> collect these lines to remove
                If rows_to_remove Is Nothing Then
                    Set rows_to_remove = cl
                Else
                    Set rows_to_remove = Union(rows_to_remove, cl)
                End If
            End If
            Dic(key) = Dic(key) + cl.Offset(, 1)
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1) ' go to the next row
        Loop
        
        If Not rows_to_remove Is Nothing Then rows_to_remove.EntireRow.Delete ' remove collected rows_to_remove with duplicate keys
        .Range(START_CELL).Offset(, 1).Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: result 2]

Comment: You are an Angel.
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Something did not work well.
One of the numbers that should be grouped disappeared. :(

I will update the post with the images